# MySQL/PHP consumes all memory

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I have problem with MySQL usage a lot of memory.

Added this in SSH to view the memory consumption.

```
ps --no-headers -Leo pmem,pcpu,command|awk 'BEGIN { print "CPU\t\ttMEM\t\tPROCNAME \n" } {{array[$3]+=$2};{array2[$3]+=$1}} END { for ( item in array) print array[item] " %" "\t" ,array2[item] " %" "\t\t", item }' |awk 'NR==1;NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -rn -k 1,1"}'
```

This image of memory consumption: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcdfq.png

- Previous image shows a high consumption of MySQL/PHP

VPS server specifications:

Burst Memory: 2048 MB

Guaranteed Memory: 1024 MB

RAID10 Storage: 60 GB

Monthly Traffic: 2000 GB

OS: Centos 6 32-bit

cPanel&WHM

How can resolve it?

Comment: reduce server load by optimizing sql querys and php scripts

Comment: don't pull back entire result sets make better use of where's and index'd joins rather than subselects and nested sql queries

Comment: to the class of this question, this answere is valid too - "Buy more Server Power"

Comment: Probably belongs are serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 0):

The good news: your site is so popular you've outgrown your hosting capacity!

The bad news: your site is so popular, you've outgrown your hosting capacity.

CPU and memory utilization alone aren't necessarily indicative of real-world performance, especially on web applications where you tend to get peaks of traffic and therefore peaks of resource utilization.

If your site is indeed slow, the cheapest option is likely to buy more CPU/memory from your hosting provider.

You could tweak the MySQL config settings to reduce memory consumption, possibly at the expense of performance.

If you don't want to pay for more iron, you'll have to optimize your site. Hard to be specific without the details, but the lowest hanging fruit is usually:

- Use caching. In order of effectiveness, you can cache pages (e.g. using a CDN), cache page snippets, and cache database queries. This should help with CPU, but may increase memory usage.
- Look at your database and find long-running queries; tune them.